# Just sharing: The minimal KML file to work with the Android Development Tools in Eclipse

Tags: android, kml

I’m collaborating with my wife on an Android app that uses the GPS Listener.  Like (almost) everyone else we’re using the ADT in Eclipse.  Also like a lot of people, we thought we could just play with Google Earth, export a KML file and pop it into the ADT.  No such luck.  Just like a lot of others discovered.
Well, after a small amount of playing around, we created a file that may be the minimal KML file that can be imported by the tool.  Even if it isn’t the minimal file, it has been reduced dramatically.   So without further ado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
   <!-- name>Title</name -->
      <Placemark><!-- name>PointName</name><description>Desc</description--><Point><coordinates>-118.383097,33.836978,193</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
      <Placemark><!-- name>PointName</name><description>Desc</description--><Point><coordinates>-118.383197,33.836988,193</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The important points in this file are:
-   the namespace identifier
-   the element nesting around the ‘tudes (Longitude, Latitude, Altitude)
-   the optional information I have commented out
To truly be minimal edit out the commented elements – but those elements turned out to be useful for me, and I left them in.  And they work with the ADT as comments or elements.  Note that I seem to need to use the full nest of elements for each location.  I did try variations on a single long list within the coordinates element to no avail.
Another helpful point may be that I used Excel to calculate the data I wanted to use, and so I also used Excel to build up my location list so that I could just cut-and-paste my changes into the file quickly.  I did so with the following line in the cells of Excel:

```
=CONCATENATE("<Placemark><!-- name>",J3,"</name><description>",K3,"</description--><Point><coordinates>",C3,",",D3,",",E3,"</coordinates></Point></Placemark>")
```

Happy Developing!

Comment: For me the key was the namespace.  The KML documentation from Google uses <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">.  When I changed to the namespace above <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2"> my KML files started loading.  As a side note.  I did not require the <Document> element in my file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
       <Placemark>
          <Point>
             <coordinates>0.0,0.0,0</coordinates>
          </Point>
       </Placemark>
    </kml>
```